# Can I hold a UK and EU driving license so that I can insure a car in the UK after moving to the EU?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, driving-license, car-insurance

I am moving from the UK to the Netherlands and will exchange my UK driving license for a Dutch one while we are still part of the EU. After Brexit, can I still claim entitlement to drive in the UK because I have previously passed a UK test?

I know I can legally drive in the UK on a EU license whilst back visiting the UK but will I be able to insure a car on my UK entitlement to drive. I will have a house in the UK, but not be officially resident. I want to keep a car there as well, and be able to keep it taxed and insured.

Comment: Licenses are issued to residents. If you live in the NL, and only visit the UK, DVLA won't issue (or re-issue) you a UK license. If, on the other hand, you say you're living in the UK when you're not...you won't be telling them the truth. As to insurance coverage...have you asked your UK insurance agent?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a UK driving licence to own, tax and insure a car in the UK.
I would highly recommend you to insure your car using your newly exchanged EU driving licence for the following reasons:

- Your insurance company might request a copy of the driving licence you declared on the insurance policy when you make a claim;
- DVLA might be notified of the exchange and refuse to issue a replacement;
- If you are unable to provide the declared driving licence, the insurer might refuse to cover the claim partially or fully;
- It is unlikely your premium will increase significantly, because the number of years you held your UK driving licence will be transferred to the EU one.

Note that if you already have an insurance policy, you need to notify your insurer of the exchange. Should they increase your premium, you need to run quotes with other insurers and bargain.

Answer (score 0):

And this is where it gets interesting. Me and my wife have been living in the uk for over 16 years. Wife have a EU driving licence which even after brexit she is allowed to use and drive with it until she's 70yo. But Churchill and some other insurance companies have refused to insure her for this very reason. And the insurance companies who did offer the insurance showing the price twice higher for EU driving licence compared to the same details with UK driving licence. Just in the case some of you kick off :) No accidents or claims, no insurance issues in the past, EU driving licence 16 years. But answering your question. I asked the same question long time ago and i was told No. When you change the EU to UK driving licence, Your EU driving licence apparently is getting sent back to your country.